# Groups not registering in X

Tags: ubuntu, group, x

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.  When I use LightDM to login and start X, I see that my secondary groups aren't loaded (running "groups" reports that I belong only to my primary group).  If I log in via console or if I su in a term in X, the groups command works normally, reporting my primary and all of my secondary groups.

Curiously, even though "groups" does not report that I'm a member of sudoers, I can still sudo.  Similarly, I can run mythfrontend, even though I'm not reportedly a member of mythtv.  It seems as if the OS recognizes my secondary groups, even if the groups command does not.

So, it doesn't seem to cause a real problem, but I'm curious if anyone else has seen this behavior.  I have three other machines running Ubuntu 16.04, but groups works normally on each of them.

Comment: what does `id` show?

Comment: id also reports that I am a member of my primary group and no other.

Comment: Are you saying that your user isn't in the `/etc/sudoers` file? Also if you reboot the system it still reports the same way? Please post your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` as well. Specifically we want to see the `group: ...` line.

Comment: My user is a member of the group sudo, which has access to all commands, per the default Ubuntu sudoers file.  But this problem isn't about sudo, really.  To test it out, I created a new user and added him to a test group.  When I logged in as that user, "groups" reported only his primary group, not the test (secondary) group.  When I su'ed to the same user, his test group was listed under "groups".

Comment: nsswitch.conf found <a href="http://phiwumbda.org/~jesse/tmp/nsswitch.conf">here</a>.

Comment: Pardon the bad link above.  Here it is: http://phiwumbda.org/~jesse/tmp/nsswitch.conf .  I am new to stackexchange.

Comment: I've got exactly the same problem here and trying hard to debug. It must have happened after a very recent apt-get dist-upgrade. Just don't get a clue why this happens. For all my shell activities, I've to do 'su - myaccount'

Comment: And I do have problem because it's not listing secondary groups. I'm having docker installed in my system, and I'm part of 'docker' group. However docker CLI doesn't work since it can't read /var/run/docker.sock. That's how I realized this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got my exact problem fixed, thanks to the defect reported here https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1581495

I had errors logged into the `/var/log/auth.log` which made me suspect problems around this.

These Ubuntu package was updated yesterday, `libpam-kwallet4:amd64 (4:5.5.5-0ubuntu1.2, 4:5.5.5-0ubuntu1.3), libpam-kwallet5:amd64 (4:5.5.5-0ubuntu1.2, 4:5.5.5-0ubuntu1.3)` and this must have caused the trouble. I just commented out the following lines in `/etc/pam.d/lightdm`

```
auth    optional        pam_kwallet.so
auth    optional        pam_kwallet5.so
```

and a reboot saved my day

Comment: I wouldn't mind understanding what those lines were supposed to do, mind you.  I've a very meager understanding of pam.

Comment: @JesseHughes - It was supposed to get my KDE wallet unlocked automatically. It doesn't happen anymore, but that's okay. It pops up a prompt for me once I log in.