# Can't log out of X!

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lightdm, x

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 and have come across an odd problem ([two](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/454593/groups-not-registering-in-x), really, but I don't think they're related).  I'm using lightdm.  After logging in, X starts as normal, but when I try to log out (using a menu item), rather than bringing me back to lightdm, X simply restarts as the same user.

If I log into a virtual console and start X from the command line, "logging out" kills X as expected.

Any ideas?  Thanks.  Let me know what diagnostics would help.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong.  The two apparently unrelated bugs were fixed by the same fix.  See the first answer at [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/454593/groups-not-registering-in-x).