# Group membership reported by id vs. contents of /etc/group

Tags: users

I have some issues with permission from various apps (such as accessing serial ports, despite being the `dialout` group, or contacting to Docker daemon, despite being in the `docker` group -- I *think*) and I need clarifications here.

When I run the `id` command, I get this:

```
uid=1000(eudoxos) gid=1000(eudoxos) groups=1000(eudoxos)
```

I understand that Debian/Ubuntu create separate primary group for each user (gid 1000).

When I look inside /etc/group, I see my username in a number of other groups (those are secondary groups, right?), such as `adm`, `sudo`, `audio`, `plugdev`, `fuse`, `docker`, `dialout` and so on). The `id` command should report those, as per [GID, current, primary, supplementary, effective and real group IDs?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18198/gid-current-primary-supplementary-effective-and-real-group-ids) but I don't see anything like that in the output. What am I missing? Is something misconfigured? (I *did* login anew after changing groups already)

**EDIT**: more information

```
$ grep eudoxos /etc/group
adm:x:4:eudoxos,syslog
dialout:x:20:eudoxos
cdrom:x:24:eudoxos
floppy:x:25:eudoxos
sudo:x:27:eudoxos
audio:x:29:eudoxos,pulse,timidity
dip:x:30:eudoxos
video:x:44:eudoxos
plugdev:x:46:eudoxos
eudoxos:x:1000:
fuse:x:104:eudoxos
lpadmin:x:111:eudoxos
admin:x:117:eudoxos
vboxusers:x:123:eudoxos
sambashare:x:129:eudoxos
pgrimaging:x:1003:eudoxos
docker:x:151:eudoxos
kvm:x:152:eudoxos
libvirt:x:153:eudoxos
```

and

```
$ grep group /etc/nsswitch.conf
group:          compat systemd
netgroup:       nis
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `grep eudoxos /etc/group` and `grep group /etc/nsswitch.conf` to your question.

Comment: added as edit :)

Comment: Hm...strange. Should work. Which distribution and version are you running? Does `groups` also do not show the groups? `id -a`?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04. `id -a` shows the same as `id` (i.e. `uid=1000(eudoxos) gid=1000(eudoxos) groups=1000(eudoxos)`) and `groups` only says `eudoxos`. ...

Comment: Just tested in a 18.04 VM and no problems at all. Did configure something on your own? Are you somehow in a docker or snap environment?

Comment: It is a plain desktop installation. But I've kept upgrading it for maybe 5 years, so there might be leftovers somewhere...

Comment: did you logout and back in again after making the group changes? changes do not show up until then (or on modern systems `sssd` could be screwing you over, somehow)

Comment: Yes, login/logout was done many times in the meantime.

Comment: I got something. When I log in the console (or via `sudo login` in terminal emulator), I have all group memberships as they should be. It means something is failing in the X11 session startup. Anyone cas guess better what it is?

Comment: Ok, found it is a bug in lightdm, I posted that finding as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in my last comment, the issue only happens when logging into the GUI session (not in terminal). This lead quickly to finding reports of the same allover forums/bugzillas. It is a bug in lightdm (which I incidentally use) which has not been fixed. Commenting out `pam_kwallet*.so` from its config file and *reboot* fixes the issue.

- [Missing groups at each startup](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/458194/missing-groups-at-each-startup/)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059856/lost-supplementary-user-groups-for-gui-login-session
- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1581495
- [Groups not registering in X](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/454593/groups-not-registering-in-x)
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/lightdm/+bug/1781418

Thanks to all those who were helpfully commenting on the issue above.